# What is the user logon id 0xe37 in event logs

Tags: login, logging, user, events, id

I have a lot of event logs where the user logon id is 0xe37 or 0xE37. I am under the impression that a logon id changes after a reboot. Many of these logs are stating that a query into an account with an unknown password, under this user logon id. What is controlling a user id that never changes?

Comment: What OS? What log? My user ID has been 501 for several decades.

Comment: Are you sure it's 0xe37 and not 0x3e7?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows *logon ID* (not user ID) `0x3e7` (not 0xe37) is a hardcoded LUID that represents the local system itself, i.e. all services running as "SYSTEM". For AD-joined machines, this logon ID has access to the machine's AD computer account.

(Other static logon IDs are 0x3e4 for "Network Service" processes and 0x3e5 for "Local Service", as [described in this article](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2224373&seqNum=7). All logon IDs can be listed using `klist sessions`.)

Comment: Thank you kindly. I am trying to work through a nasty trojan and event logs sure are hard to discern between good and bad. I see a lot of logs Now that include the terms hive and hive length. I assume these are logs showing something in the bad catagory

Comment: ["Hive"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-hives) is the usual Windows term for a Registry database (e.g. each user's ntuser.dat storing their individual HKCU hive).